# JAVA path error in hadoop

Tags: 14.04, command-line, java, paths, hadoop

I installed hadoop watching a youtube video. while I try to run this in terminal it gives me this error

```
srimanth@srimanth-Inspiron-N5110:~$ /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop version /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop: line 144: /usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin//bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I have java in `/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/` but I dont know why the error is showing a different path.

I have setup the path in `hadoop-env.sh` like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/ export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
```

I did the same in`.bashrc`:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop JAVA_HOME=/usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/bin export JAVA_HOME PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME export PATH
```

If you need any extra info please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you have included `bin/` folder in your `JAVA_HOME` path.

Remove it, so that your `JAVA_HOME` should  look like `usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31`

i.e

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/iib/java/jdk1.8.0_31/`